# library not found for -lPods-Kurbside-AFNetworkActivityLogger

Tags: ios, afnetworking, cocoapods

I have dependecy for AFNetworkActivityLogger in POD file

```
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger'
```

When i run pod install i am getting the message like AFNetworkActivityLogger has been downloaded.

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using AFNetworkActivityLogger (2.0.4)
```

But when i build my project i am getting the below error message

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-Kurbside-AFNetworkActivityLogger
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you building your project from `.xcworkspace`?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I posted solution to related question. [Take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30533603/2243451), maybe it can help you too. Another thing to try is `pod install` to reinstall cocoapods.