# Cocoapods Completely Broke

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods

To start: I'm using Cocoapods 0.37.2, XCode 6.3.1 compiling for iOS 8.3

My project worked just fine before I ran a basic "pod update" now it's completely refusing to compile. I'm quite positive this has nothing to do with the pods themselves. Specifically the error I'm getting is this:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/user_name/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-bjozswzeepmhacfkeimeepxzcxgb/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include'
ld: library not found for -lPods-AppName-AFNetworking
```

Podfile is this:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, "8.0"

def shared_pods
    pod 'SocketRocket'
    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'DateTools'
    pod 'Spotify-iOS-SDK'
end

target "AppName" do
    shared_pods
end

target "AppNameTests" do
    shared_pods
end
```

I have cleared DerivedData (many many times), cleaned my builds, restarted XCode, restarted my machine, I have ensured my config files and linker config lists are set up correctly. I've been using Cocoapods for years and never had this much trouble.

Completely frustrated and confused... questioning sanity.

Any help?

Comment: Did you by any chance accidentally open the `.xcodeproj` files instead of the `.xcworkspace` file?

Comment: No, definitely not (even double checked).

Comment: If you go to Editor -> Scheme -> Manage schemes, do you have Pods added as a scheme?

Comment: No, but the pods are being complied already, so I'm not sure why it would matter?

Answer (score 1):

Information from CocoaPods [troubleshooting doc](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html). Hope this helps you.

> If Xcode complains when linking, e.g. Library not found for -lPods, it
>   doesn't detect the implicit dependencies:
>
> - Go to Product > Edit Scheme
> - Click on Build
> - Add the Pods static
>     library, and make sure it's at the top of the list
> - Clean and build again
> - If that doesn't work, verify that the source for the spec you
>     are trying to include has been pulled from GitHub. Do this by looking
>     in /Pods/. If it
>     is empty (it should not be), verify that the
>     ~/.cocoapods/master//.podspec has the correct git hub url
>     in it.
> - If still doesn't work, check your Xcode build locations
>     settings. Go to Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data -> Advanced
>     and set build location to "Relative to Workspace".

Comment: I just tried all three of those suggestions, and the you were right, the Pods library was missing. However, the problem is still persisting, exactly the same errors.